# React web app gets a set-cookie header but doesn't save it

Tags: reactjs, express, session, fetch-api, express-session

I have a very simple login system, which takes a username and a password from a user, and when the form is submitted the data is posted to an express http app.

The login function at the react app is as following:

```
    async function login(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        setRequestState(REQUEST_STATE.pending)

        const request = `${SERVER_URL}/login`;
        const formData = new FormData();
        
        formData.append("username",data["username"])
        formData.append("password",data["password"])

        const response = await fetch(request, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            enctype:"multipart/form-data",
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        })

        if(!response.ok){
            if(response.status === 401){
                console.log("username or password are inccorect")
                setDisplayError(response.status)
            }
            if(response.status === 500){
                console.log("internal server error")
                setDisplayError(response.status)
            }
            setRequestState(REQUEST_STATE.no_request)
            return;
        }

        setRequestState(REQUEST_STATE.success)
        // navigate("/dashboard")
    }
```

the response is successful consistently when the right data is entered.

I use express-sessions to handle sessions, the setup code for the sessions is as following:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const loginRouter = require('./src/routes/login.js');
const session = require('express-session')

const app = express()

app.use(
    cors({
        origin:true,
        credentials:'same-origin',
}))

app.use(session({
  secret: 'test',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
//   store: sessionStore,
  cookie: { 
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'none',
}
}));


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.use('/login', loginRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT ,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

login router is as following:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const router = express.Router()
const {getLogin,postLogin, authenticateLogin} = require('../controllers/login')

upload = multer({})

router.post("/", upload.array(0), authenticateLogin, postLogin)
router.get("/", getLogin)

module.exports=router
```

login controller is as following:

```
const {pool} = require('../../sqlconfig')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const postLogin = (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).send({success:true});
}

const getLogin = (req, res) => {
    // console.log("get this login betch")
    console.log(req.session.id)
    if(req.session.userId){
        return res.status(200).send({success:true});
    }
    // console.log("couldn't get login")
    return res.status(401).send({success:false});
}

const authenticateLogin = async (req, res, next) => {

    const dict = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    
    const username = dict["username"];
    const password = dict["password"];

    if(!dict || !username || !password) {
        // console.log("Access deneid")
        return res.status(401).send({error:"Access denied"});
    }
    try{
        const query = "SELECT passwrd FROM admins WHERE admins.username=?";
        const [result] = await pool.execute(query,[username])

        if(result.length <= 0){
            return res.status(401).send({error:"Access denied"});
        }

        const passwordInDB = result[0].passwrd;

        if(!passwordInDB){
            return res.status(401).send({error:"Access denied"});
        }
        
        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordInDB);
        // console.log(match)

        if(!match){
            return res.status(401).send({error:"Access denied"});
        }
        
        const queryUserId = "SELECT id FROM admins WHERE admins.username=?";
        const [resultUserId] = await pool.execute(queryUserId,[username])
        
        req.session.userId = resultUserId[0].id;
        console.log("logged in successfuly!")
        console.log(req.session)
        
        next()
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

module.exports={
    authenticateLogin,
    postLogin,
    getLogin
}
```

when login post is called, a session does get created,
and a cookie is sent back to the react application:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJLFy.png)

but doesn't get saved:
[saved cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFN3z.png)

Comment: Change `credentials: 'same-origin'` to `credentials: 'include'` and see if it helps